# How can we start develop Linux imaging Tool(Capture and Apply) to restore/backup Linux OS image

Tags: linux, windows, operating-system, restore, winpe

I want to develop a Tool which is responsible to provide and restore/backup feature for Linux OS.
In the case of Windows, we have WIMGAPI and WINPE environment so we can use that API to develop an imaging tool for Windows OS. Similar thing I want to develop on Linux.
Is there anything to start to develop an imaging tool for Linux, I'm not familiar with Linux OS, So please let me know how can I start in Linux.

Comment: I think [packer](https://www.packer.io/) does it already

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems. Requests for tool recommendations and more general issues are off topic. (sorry). Your Q seems  more appropriate for https://quora.com , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.